# What happens when you use C++?

Tags: c++

I'm just being introduced to C++, and want to know a basic question.... 
What happens when using C++?  Is there anywhere I can see a working example?  Textbooks break it down, segment by segment.  I would really like to SEE what happens.
ANY suggestion would be appreciated.  Hope MY question is not too vague.
Thanks!

Comment: When you use C++, lots of things can happen. Once, when I used it, I made an interdimensional rift.

Comment: some say when you use C++, the Java angels weep tears of blood.

Comment: Every time I use C++, my head starts to hurt!  Should I see a doctor about this?

Comment: I fear your question is to vague. Do you want to know what can be done with C++ or what happens inside your computer if you start a program written with C++?

Comment: If you look at this page using Firefox, you see C++ at work.

Comment: You should be clearer into what you mean with 'what happens' and with 'when using c++'. Are you interested in how the process from source code to executable goes? what does the compiler do? what does the linker do? how are different c++ program from Java/.NET?

Comment: @UnhipGlint  I don't think a doctor can help. I've come to conclusion that you have to born for wrapping your head around C++ completely. I'm certainly not born that way :)

Comment: @Thomas Owens, you tried to dereference a null pointer, didn't you?

Comment: Every time you dereference a NULL pointer, an angel loses it's halo :(

Comment: @Eric Perhaps...perhaps. I'll never reveal what I did, since I don't want other people to go through that horror.

Comment: As already said, your question is very vague. Do you mean what happens when you write some C++ code and press the "build" button? Or an example of some software written in C++? Or something else? Since this question got closed, feel free to start another one, but be more specific about what you want to know. "using C++" can mean a lot of different things, and it's hard to know what answer you're looking for. If you've got a concrete example, all the better.

Comment: every time you use c++ Bjarne kills Schroedinger's cat

Comment: Glad to see this got voted back up to 0. Seemed a bit harsh to downvote it. It's not easy to formulate good questions when you're new to programming.

Comment: @jalf: if the OP is that new, it's possible there is no question that can be asked. I sympathize. When I was that new, I was told to go down to the Computer Center and get an account, start learning to program, and to LEAVE PEOPLE ALONE! I sure showed _them_!

Answer (score 10):

You get into the office around 8:30am, get some tea, and you sit down and run a program called an IDE. It lets you type code with the keyboard, such as:

```
(*m_pHopeThisIsntNull)->doIt();
```

You can then hit F5 and the code runs and you find out it doesn't work the way you expected. Pretty soon it's 5:30pm.

Comment: One string a day... I thought it is good for ASM developers, not for C++ :)

Comment: No, a line of C++ takes weeks to get right! For example, I imagine that line is calling the overloaded `*` operator on a type which returns a type that overloads the `->` operator, which returns another type that returns the `->` operator, which returns a type that has a public member variable called `doIt`, which is of a type that overloads the `()` operator to return a temporary that constructs and then immediately destructs.

Comment: @Earwicker +1 if you can show me an example of that in action. :P

Comment: @Jeremy - wasn't intended as a serious criticism of C++, you can hide complexity in a small space in any powerful language. In C# the expression `() => x` effectively declares two classes all by itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to learn C++, you cannot just read from the textbook -- programming is learned best through hands-on practice. You should get a C++ compiler and run through the textbook examples yourself.

Comment: Sing it, brother.  This is absolutely the best advice.  There's a huge difference between "book smarts" and working experience when it comes to this beast of a language.

Answer (score 2):

When I use C++, other programmers bow down to me because of my awesomeness. But that's just my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a short session with your TA (at an American university, this is the graduate student who helps with the hands-on stuff, does the grading, etc., as a help to the professor) is in order. Get him/her to show you how to use whatever IDE (integrated development environment) your class is requiring/suggesting. Or wait for your lab session, where you will learn this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a debugger to execute your program step by step, looking at the variables. If that's not enough, debuggers can also show you the a disassembled version of the machine code along with the processor's registers.

Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

You are using C++! your browser is written in C++!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see it step by step:

Set a breakpoint at the first line and start in debug (F5 in Visual Studio).  You can step through the program step-by-step and see what's going on with varying granularity (Step Over or Step Into - usually F10 and F11 in Visual Studio).  Stepping into will follow a function call whereas F10 will call it, and step forward over it after it returns.

If you want to see what's going on at a lower level you can use disassemble on  your code.

I've used Visual Studio/Windows stuff here b/c that's what I'm most used to but these things are in every major C++ IDE I've seen.